# how is the process to allocate tests to different users within a test run in kiwi tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have a question where I would like to know how you would solve my lite problem.

I work as a test coordinator for a small team and when I'm only cordinating my team, kiwi is of great use but sometimes we have a common test where it can be up to 50 people. What we are doing today is send a small document to each person with some cases that the person should test and then the person send back a document with how the test went.

What I would like to do in kiwi is create a test plan with e.g 200 test cases and then create a test run and when user x log in he/she should only see the tests that he/she should do. I also need to get the numbers right after the test run is finished. E.g. amount of issue found, how many test cases failed aso in the testplan.

I guess that the way it should be is create a test plan and a test run and then assign the test cases to the different users BUT then I need to change all the test cases each time we do this test because I don't want the same user do the same test cases each time. For this to work I think there need to be a assignee field (there is) for the test cases after I have added them to a test run that is easy to change directly from the test run -> test case list.

If there is anyone that has any suggestion that could work for me please share it!

Answer (score 1):

Could you elaborate on what exactly is the issue?

The scenario which you have described is valid - you create test run and assign testers to ti via Assignee field directly from test run view. Here you also see the number of passed / failed tests and reported bugs.

If you use the same test case in new test run and want to change the tester (assignee) you have a history under test case details in field Executions where all previous test executions along with testers are shown.

Comment: I think you solved my problem. It was not clear to me that the assignee field on the test cases inside the test run was only for that test run.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess that the way it should be is create a test plan and a test run and then assign the test cases to the different users BUT then I need to change all the test cases each time we do this test because I don't want the same user do the same test cases each time. For this to work I think there need to be a assignee field (there is) for the test cases after I have added them to a test run that is easy to change directly from the test run -> test case list.

This is correct. Individual testers can use filtering (or just Ctrl+F on the page) to see only the executions they are assigned to.

If you want to vary the assignments between different test runs you can do that either manually or by a small script using the API. For example: create a new TR, then call the script with NEW-TR-ID OLD-TR-ID and shuffle the assignments between users. You will have to create your own script but consider contributing it to https://github.com/kiwitcms/api-scripts if you do.